# No of solutions for an equation with variable $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, recreational-mathematics

IF $x-5=0$ then $x=5$ (One solution $x=5$)
When multiplying $x$ to both sides we get (In a balance if you did same thing on both sides equation will not change)
$x^2 -5x=0\cdot x$ (anything multiplied by $0$ is $0$)
$$x^2-5x=0$$
Here $x$ has two solutions ($x=0$ and $x=5$)
HOW WOULD THIS HAPPEN?

Comment: Because you multiplied by $x$?

Comment: Because like you said, anything times 0 is 0. So you could still get your original solution $x=5$ or you could have multiplied by zero meaning $x=0$.

Comment: Multiplying with $x$ is no equivalence-transformation because (like here) $x$ can be $0$ and if we multiply with $0$, we get $0=0$, which is always satisfied.

Comment: It is not correct usage to refer to the same variable as both capital $X$ and lower-case $x. \qquad$

Comment: Many fake-proofs base on a harmless seeming division by a term that is $0$. Since we are not allowed to divide by $0$, it can easily be that a contradiction arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you multiply anything by zero, the answer is zero, so you can't reverse the process and divide by zero. You have either $x=0$, which doesn't depend on what the original equation was, or the original equation holds.

You can't "do anything" to an equation and keep the same solutions. You have to do something reversible. Multiplying by zero is not reversible.

Answer (score 0):

You're multiplying two things and getting $0:$
$$
x(x-5) = 0.
$$
That means either $x=0$ or $x-5=0.$